# Using cycle to Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, cycle, django-cms

I am developing a Django application, i had some problem,

I hope to do the following effects on Django,

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Django Code,

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
{% for child in children %}
{% cycle 'active' 'last' as cssmenu silent %}
<li class="{{ cssmenu }}">
    <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
    {% if child.children %}
    <ul>
        {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Could you help me?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you're having...?

Comment: i dont think that is the right way of using cycle. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle

Comment: Thank you Jesse,http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2057717/Screenshots/bu50.png

Comment: Karthikr, How should I set ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not what `cycle` is for: it's for alternating between two or more alternatives. You don't want that at all.

Instead, just use the `forloop` attributes:

```
{% for child in children %}
    <li class="{% if forloop.first %}active{% elif forloop.last %}last{% endif %}">...</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Although I suppose you don't want the first one to always be active, but you haven't given any information about how you do want to determine where 'active' goes.